# Visual studio 2017 not indenting code properly

Tags: visual-studio-2017, text-editor, ident

I've just installed Visual Studio 2017 and began writing my ASP.NET MVC 5 web app. I've come across this issue where the indentation of code is not correct. What I noticed is that when I hit the semicolon on `var priv = new Phonebase();` it will shift out of the scope that it belongs to.

I've played around with indentation settings for C#, but I couldn't remedy the issue. I've tried *smart* indentation and *block* indentation. Does anyone know how I can get Visual Studio to ident lines of code properly?

[image: Incorrect indentation]

Comment: Have you tried playing with the tabs space/indention options at Tools->options->Text Editor->All languages->(select langauge)?

Answer (score 1):

I found a .editorconfig file in the root of my c drive (c:\.editorconfig). When I deleted this file, this issue went away for me.

See [this page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/44231/cant-set-indent-level-to-4-spaces-in-vs-2017.html) for more information and fixes with .editorconfig